# HTTP-500 after creating new web applications

Tags: web-application

When I create a new web application, all existing web applications stop responding. They start giving HTTP-500 errors but I can't see a single entry in ULS logs about the error. So I can't know where to start looking for problems. This is really strange, I've never seen such a problem before.

Can you guys think of something?

Comment: Turn up verbosity in ULS logs and try again. Check IIS, web sites running, application pools up, accounts running pools are not locked. Is central admin still running? Try browsing to one of the _layout pages like settings.aspx

Comment: Check the Windows Event Logs.